# How to store multiple values in single column where use less memory?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of *users* where 1 column stores user's "roles".
We can assign *multiple roles* to particular user.

Then I want to store role IDs in the "roles" column.

But how can I store multiple values into a single column to save memory in a way that is easy to use? For example, storing using a comma-delimited field is not easy and uses memory.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does save memory mean to you?

Comment: save memory of mysql means in size and easy to use

Comment: It won't be easier to use, and it won't save any memory. Just use multiple columns.

Comment: Could you post your schema?

Comment: I've made some small tweaks to correct the grammar. Feel free to revert this if it changes the question too much.

Comment: Try this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977270/how-to-insert-multiple-of-values-in-a-single-field-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977270/how-to-insert-multiple-of-values-in-a-single-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 15):

If a user can have multiple roles, it is probably better to have a `user_role` table that stores this information. It is normalised, and will be much easier to query.

A table like:

```
user_id | role
--------+-----------------
      1 | Admin
      2 | User
      2 | Admin
      3 | User
      3 | Author
```

Will allow you to query for all users with a particular role, such as `SELECT user_id, user.name FROM user_role JOIN user WHERE role='Admin'` rather than having to use string parsing to get details out of a column.

Amongst other things this will be faster, as you can index the columns properly and will take marginally more space than any solution that puts multiple values into a single column - which is antithetical to what relational databases are designed for.

The reason this shouldn't be stored is that it is inefficient, for the reason DCoder states on the [comment to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18605879/764357). To check if a user has a role, every row of the user table will need to be scanned, and then the "roles" column will have to be scanned using string matching - regardless of how this action is exposed, the RMDBS will need to perform string operations to parse the content. These are very expensive operations, and not at all good database design.

If you **need** to have a single column, I would strongly suggest that **you no longer have a technical problem, but a people management one**. Adding additional tables to an existing database that is under development, should not be difficult. If this isn't something you are authorised to do, explain to why the extra table is needed to the right person - because **[munging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_%28computer_term%29) multiple values into a single column is a bad, *bad* idea**.

Comment: Ok.. but must be store in single column as i describe in my question

Comment: @harsh4u There is no technical reason this needs to be a single column, so I've added some more detail.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use bitwise logic with MySQL. `role_id` must be in BASE 2 (0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...)

```
role_id | label
--------+-----------------
      1 | Admin
      2 | User
      4 | Author

user_id | name  | role
--------+-----------------
      1 | John  | 1
      2 | Steve | 3
      3 | Jack  | 6
```

Bitwise logic allows you to select all user roles

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE role & 1
-- returns all Admin users

SELECT * FROM users WHERE role & 5
-- returns all users who are admin or Author because 5 = 1 + 4

SELECT * FROM users WHERE role & 6
-- returns all users who are User or Author because 6 = 2 + 4
```

Comment: our role can have 100 value, this solution may be not optimize, Do you have any other ideal ?

Answer (score 2):

From your question what I got,

Suppose, you have to table. one is "meal" table and another one is "combo_meal" table. Now I think you want to store multiple meal_id inside one combo_meal_id without separating coma[,]. And you said that it'll make your DB to more standard.

If I not getting wrong from your question then please read carefully my suggestion bellow. It may be help you.

First think is your concept is right. Definitely it'll give you more standard DB.

For this you have to create one more table [ example table: combo_meal_relation ] for referencing those two table data. May be one visible example will clear it.

```
meal table

+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|  id  |  name  | serving   |  price  |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|  1   | soup1  |  2 person |  12.50  |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|  2   | soup2  |  2 person |  15.50  |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|  3   | soup3  |  2 person |  23.00  |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|  4   | drink1 |  2 person |  4.50   |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|  5   | drink2 |  2 person |  3.50   |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|  6   | drink3 |  2 person |  5.50   |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|  7   | frui1  |  2 person |  3.00   |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|  8   | fruit2 |  2 person |  3.50   |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|  9   | fruit3 |  2 person |  4.50   |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+

combo_meal table

+------+--------------+-----------+
|  id  |  combo_name  | serving   |
+------+--------------+-----------+
|  1   |   combo1     |  2 person |
+------+--------------+-----------+
|  2   |   combo2     |  2 person |
+------+--------------+-----------+
|  4   |   combo3     |  2 person |
+------+--------------+-----------+

combo_meal_relation

+------+--------------+-----------+
|  id  | combo_meal_id|  meal_id  |
+------+--------------+-----------+
|  1   |      1       |      1    |
+------+--------------+-----------+
|  2   |      1       |      2    |
+------+--------------+-----------+
|  3   |      1       |      3    |
+------+--------------+-----------+
|  4   |      2       |      4    |
+------+--------------+-----------+
|  5   |      2       |      2    |
+------+--------------+-----------+
|  6   |      2       |      7    |
+------+--------------+-----------+
```

When you search inside table then it'll generate faster result.

search query:

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    combo_meal cm
JOIN    meal m
ON      m.id = cm.meal_id
WHERE   cm.combo_id = 1
```

Hopefully you understand :)

Comment: I understand your solution and would also go for something like this. But I would have done it without ny id column in `combo_meal_relation`. I think that 1 column is un-necessary and rest everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
INSERT INTO table (id, roles) VALUES ('', '2,3,4');
```

Then to find it use `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: That does not improve performance at all, the DB still has to scan the entire table to find matches.

Comment: op wanted single column/same table, so this is a good answer IMO. Op might be better without added complexity of multi-table.. who knows :)

Comment: @akostadinov This is a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/226333). While the user is asking for a thing, in this case that is most definitely not what they want. A multi-table solution will be cleaner, faster and much easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, well, I've seen custom solutions were things are edited by hand directly into database. In such case it will be easier to have everything in one table. Not very professional though. In any case, the answer is perfectly valid as far as I see so does not deserve -1. It is perhaps not the best solution but not dangerous either.

Comment: I'd like to think StackOverflow isn't a place that encourages solutions where we "hand edit directly into a database". The OP asked a question, and the best answer is "don't do what you are thinking, do it properly".

Comment: And I'd like to think, that when you give someone an answer he asks for, and not the answer he actually need, its not really a bad answer at all.

Comment: JTC - The problem is that your answer, as @DCoder points out, is that it is very inefficient when querying - and I'd assume user roles will be read much more than they are written, so read optimisation is much more important than what ever 'memory savings' the OP thinks they'll get.

Answer (score 0):

As you might already know, storing multiple values in a cell goes against 1NF form.
 If youre fine with that, using a json column type is a great way and has good methods to query properly.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(column_name, '"value 2"', '$')
```

Will return any entry with json data like

```
[
    "value",
    "value 2",
    "value 3"
]
```

Youre using json, so remember, youre query performance will go down the drain.