# how to insert multiple of values in a single field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i want to insert multiple values into a single field, i don't know how to achieve this i'm using a long-text data type field. And also tell me how to fetch these a value only one separate value at a time.

Comment: What is the reason to do that?

Comment: It is not recommended to store multiple values in a relational database like Mysql. You should re-think your design. If is extremely necessary, consider using a default separator like comma.

Comment: I a creating a building's flats availability system for that i am using a field name "available" and want to insert in it all flat's number that are available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Insert Mutliple values in a single Field:**

For inserting the flat no's in a single field, use `implode` and the values separated by comma.

```
$r=implode(",",$available);
$insert=mysql_query("insert into flatdetails(available) value ('$r')")
```

For retrieve the values from database use, `explode` to separate out all the values..

For Retrieve the values using 
**$i=explode(",",$r);**

```
<?php
$select_tbl=mysql_query("select * from flatdetails",$conn);
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_object($select_tbl))
{
$r=$fetch->available;


$i=explode(",",$r);


echo $i[0]."</br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Vig Nesh, its working properly but how to know that how many values in array list. for this i'm using following code but the while never ends, can you help me how to get the number of values in array--              '`while($fetch=mysql_fetch_object($sql_emp))
{
$r=$fetch->avl;


$i=explode(",",$r);
$a = 0;
while( $a <= $i)
{
echo "available=". $i[$a]."</br>";
$a++;
}

}'`

Comment: hello Vig Nesh, please help me to give me answer?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to store multiple values into a single column. If you really want to do that store your strings as coma separated. And when reading back from database you can use php explode function. [Php explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

I'll give you another option to store

Assume your strings are str1,str2,str3

First if you use your method it will be like below. which is not a good idea i think.

[image]

I think following is the good method

[image]

Comment: if a separated by comma than when i fetch this field value it fetches also these commas and i want to fetch only a single value at a time

Comment: Thats why i included php exploded function in my answer. please check that too. You can remove coma and take each value using that

Comment: yeah this idea really attract me ,, thanks for give me another way to implement my idea , thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, MySQL does not have any data types that could help your use case. Well, actually it has a "set" data type, but it only allows for up to 60-something members if I recall correctly.

You can try using BLOB as your column type and store serialized data in there (i.e. JSON, protocol buffers).

However, I would recommend that you re-evaluate your DB's design. You're breaking [the first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), and it's a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: well let me try by using BLOB :)

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode to encode the content and then store it in db field and when you retrieve the value then use json_decode   ( Same like wordpress )

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Array and Implode functionality of PHP. Create an array and implode it by comma. For example---

Suppose you have three fields then get values of these input fields and make an array.

```
$arr = array(); // Declare an array

$arr[] = $_POST['FirstField'];
$arr[] = $_POST['SecondField'];
$arr[] = $_POST['ThirdField'];
```

// As more as you have input fields.

Then make it a string like

```
$insertValue = implode(',',$arr); // This will create a string containing all your fields values and you can save it in single field.
```

Just use this single variable in your insert query.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

db connect file with PDO save as config.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'clsrepair';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection error: ".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

then in you desire file:

```
if(isset($_POST['your_form']))
{
   try {
       $leavingEquipment = implode(', ', $_POST['leavingEquipment']);
       $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO orderForm (orderNo,leavingEquipment) VALUES (?,?)");
       $statement->execute(array($_POST['orderNo'],$leavingEquipment));
$success_message = "Order's has been inserted successfully.";
      }
    catch(Exception $e) {
            $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding additional field to your apartmat table wher you writte for example 1 for rented (not available)
0 for available

query all apartments accordint to 0 and you got your list of all available appartments.