# SELECT name From joined table where joined table row id in set of parent table column

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables. `skill` and `userskill`.

*skill rows*

```
type:1
name:'Web Development'
id: 1
```

---

```
type:1
name:'Graphic Design'
id: 2
```

*userskill row*

```
user_id: 1
skill_type: 1
skills: '1,2'
```

The following query only returns the first row, not both rows as i had expected. i was wondering why, and if this type of joining is even possible/a good practice.

*query*

```
SELECT b.name,b.type 
FROM userskill a 
JOIN skill b ON a.skill_type=b.type 
WHERE a.user_id="1" AND b.id IN(a.skills)
```

You may be wondering why the query doesn't try to constrain on `skill_type` this is because i want to return a list of all user skills, which can then be sorted by type in the application. this is more suitable than performing many queries in my opinion.

Comment: Don't store lists as comma delimited strings.  SQL does not support what you ware trying to do.  The `UserSkills` table should have one row per user and per skill.

Comment: fyi, it works with find in set. @GordonLinoff http://puu.sh/mPmJ3/1212ad07ea.png whether its a good practice or not is another story.

Comment: . . Very bad practice.

Comment: could you perhaps elaborate on why it is a bad practice? does it lead to poor performance?

Answer (score 2):

User skill table has an attribute with multiple values, you should allow multiple rows for the userskill table with the same information but different skills

Example:

```
user_id skill_type skill
1       1          1
1       1          2
```

The primary key in this case would be all the attributes

Reference: [How to store multiple values in single column where use less memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605669/how-to-store-multiple-values-in-single-column-where-use-less-memory)

Edit

Query will be:

```
SELECT b.name,b.type 
FROM userskill a 
JOIN skill b ON a.skill_type=b.type 
WHERE a.user_id="1"
```

Comment: then how would i be able to return the list in one query? that seems horribly inneficient for writing too.

Comment: @r3wt this is the correct way to create tables. Check the update for the query

Comment: @r3wt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605669/how-to-store-multiple-values-in-single-column-where-use-less-memory In your case, you don't need to create another table because userskill should be defined similar to my example

Comment: i'm not a fan of implementing a greater write load to the application. even if the read is slower because of this design choice, thats ok. a slow query can be cached on demand as it is updated with memcached, and persisted later on to the db, a huge backlog of pending writes can't and slows the entire system, even if produces a more efficient select query. also, removing a record would cause the index to need to be recalculated, placing even higher load on the database. the only time this query will run is in cases where the cache cluster has failed. i need to think about this.

Comment: @r3wt the method I suggested is what every book and reference will tell you to do. I am sure that no one will answer your question by encouraging you doing the wrong practice.