# Query on binary column to get all results as multiple rows

Tags: mysql, binary

As described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40233066/2342628

I have used binary column in a table. Now, I need to retrieve data from that table joining it's reference table (There is no foreign key relation in between these two tables).

For example reference table **t1** where role_id is the binary column

**t1**

```
 role_id | label
 --------+-----------------
       1 | Admin
       2 | User
       4 | Author
```

and table **t2** where roles is the binary column

**t2**

```
user_id | name  | roles
--------+-----------------
      1 | John  | 1
      2 | Steve | 3
      3 | Jack  | 6
```

Then, How can I query to get the results like below?

```
user_id | role_id
--------+---------
      3 | 2
      3 | 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several iterations I found the exact query.

> select t1.user_id, t2.role_id from t1, t2 where t1.role_id & t2.roles;